# DNS configuration using Route 53 and Scalr

Tags: domain-name-system, scalr

Possible bad configure of DNS using Route 53 and Scalr

Hi,

I’m trying to configure the DNS for hosted Scalr. Unfortunately I can’t point the nameservers to Scalr directly, as it’s not allowed by the DK Hostmaster. So I have to use Route 53..

**Domain.dk points towards Amazons Route 53 nameservers:**

```
ns-1191.awsdns-20.org
ns-1604.awsdns-08.co.uk
ns-485.awsdns-60.com
ns-831.awsdns-39.net
```

**At Route 53 I have the following configured:**

```
domain.dk    NS    ns1.scalr.net
                   ns2.scalr.net
                   ns3.scalr.net
                   ns4.scalr.net

domain.dk   SOA    ns-1191.awsdns-20.org 
                   awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com

*.domain.dk NS     ns1.scalr.net
                   ns2.scalr.net
                   ns3.scalr.net
                   ns4.scalr.net
```

**And last, at Scalr I have my DNS zone configured:**

```
Domain.dk   NS     ns1.scalr.net
                   ns2.scalr.net
                   ns3.scalr.net
                   ns4.scalr.net
```

In addition at Scalr I also have the following checked:
Automatically create A records for farm and role.

Would the above work? And what about subdomains? I guess I can wait 72 hours to find out, but I really want to find out beforehand..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried asking Scalr to get the DK-Hostmaster approval they need in order to host DK domains?  It is no longer associated with a free, and since they already have their DNS infrastructure, it's a matter of filling out a document and sending it to DK Hostmaster.

Comment: There: https://www.dk-hostmaster.dk/english/technical-administration/dns-server-contacts/forms/approval-of-name-servers/?no_cache=1

Comment: Yes, I asked nicely - However that's going to take some time..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that that's going to work, because DNS clients aren't going to expect another NS delegation from Route 53. Your options are to delegate a subdomain from Route 53 to Scalr, or to delve into the unknown and try a [DNAME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNAME#DNAME_record) record from Route 53 to a different domain hosted by Scalr (although I'm not sure that A records on the root will work).

Comment: Route53 does not support DNAME (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=221418) and as far as I can tell, no other DNS service provider does either.  If you want or need DNAME, you have to do it yourself by setting up BIND/PowerDNS/etc. and running/managing it.